# Expedition Problem from SPOJ. Using heap data structure

Tags: c++, algorithm, heap, greedy, max-heap

Problem [Expedition](https://www.spoj.com/problems/EXPEDI/)

> A group of cows grabbed a truck and ventured on an expedition deep
> into the jungle. Being rather poor drivers, the cows unfortunately
> managed to run over a rock and puncture the truck's fuel tank. The
> truck now leaks one unit of fuel every unit of distance it travels.
>
> To repair the truck, the cows need to drive to the nearest town (no
> more than 1,000,000 units distant) down a long, winding road. On this
> road, between the town and the current location of the truck, there
> are N (1 <= N <= 10,000) fuel stops where the cows can stop to acquire
> additional fuel (1..100 units at each stop).
>
> The jungle is a dangerous place for humans and is especially dangerous
> for cows. Therefore, the cows want to make the minimum possible number
> of stops for fuel on the way to the town. Fortunately, the capacity of
> the fuel tank on their truck is so large that there is effectively no
> limit to the amount of fuel it can hold. The truck is currently L
> units away from the town and has P units of fuel (1 <= P <=
> 1,000,000).
>
> Determine the minimum number of stops needed to reach the town, or if
> the cows cannot reach the town at all.
>
> **Input** The first line of the input contains an integer t representing the number of test cases. Then t test cases follow. Each
> test case has the follwing form:
>
> - Line 1: A single integer, N
> - Lines 2..N+1: Each line contains two space-separated integers describing a fuel stop: The first integer is the distance from the
>   town to the stop; the second is the amount of fuel available at that
>   stop.
> - Line N+2: Two space-separated integers, L and P
>
> **Output** For each test case, output a single integer giving the minimum number of fuel stops necessary to reach the town. If it is not
> possible to reach the town, output -1.
>
> **Example**
> **Input**:
>
> 1
>
> 4
>
> 4 4
>
> 5 2
>
> 11 5
>
> 15 10
>
> 25 10
>
> **Output**:
>
> 2
>
> Input details The truck is 25 units away from the town; the truck has
> 10 units of fuel.  Along the road, there are 4 fuel stops at distances
> 4, 5, 11, and 15 from the town (so these are initially at distances
> 21, 20, 14, and 10 from the truck).  These fuel stops can supply up to
> 4, 2, 5, and 10 units of fuel, respectively.
>
> Output details: Drive 10 units, stop to acquire 10 more units of fuel,
> drive 4 more units, stop to acquire 5 more units of fuel, then drive
> to the town.

My attempt

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
 
int run_case() {
    int N;
    cin >> N;
    vector<pair<int, int>> biasDistance;
    biasDistance.emplace_back(0, 0); // location of tower
    priority_queue<pair<int, int>, vector<pair<int, int>>, less<>> biasFuel;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        int a, b;
        cin >> a >> b;
        biasDistance.emplace_back(a, b);
    }
    sort(biasDistance.begin(), biasDistance.end());
 
    int L, P;
    cin >> L >> P;
 
    int res = 0;
    while (!biasDistance.empty()) {
        // which points we can reach
        while (P >= L - biasDistance.back().first && !biasDistance.empty()) {
            biasFuel.push({biasDistance.back().second, biasDistance.back().first});
            biasDistance.pop_back();
        }
 
        if (biasDistance.empty()) { // if we can reach all the points
            return res;
        } else { // if not enough fuel to next point --> need stop somewhere
            while (P < L - biasDistance.back().first && !biasFuel.empty()) {
                int addedFuel = biasFuel.top().first;
                int location = biasFuel.top().second;
                biasFuel.pop();
                if (L >= location) {
                    P = P - (L - location) + addedFuel;
                    L = location;
                } else {
                    P += addedFuel;
                }
                res++; // stop here
            }
        }
 
        // still not enough fuel to next point
        if (P < L - biasDistance.back().first) {
            return -1;
        }
    }
 
    return res;
}
 
 
int main() {
    int T;
    cin >> T;
    while (T > 0) {
        cout << run_case() << "\n";
        T--;
    }
}
```

I used a (max heap of fuel) for collecting a list point that the group can reach. And use fuel when the vehicle is out of fuel.

I tried to spend a lot of time to solve this problem. But i failed almost tests with the answer is -1

Don't know why. Could you help me?

Comment: Suggestion: determine an input set that causes errors and then step through the program with the debugger that came with your development tools to find out why the inputs cause the error. Fix the problem and move on to the next bug. You'll find this approach far more efficient than asking questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: `while (P >= L - biasDistance.back().first && !biasDistance.empty()) {` looks suspicious. You should probably reverse the order of the tests since the first is UB unless the second holds.

Answer (score 0):

Since our capacity is unlimited, we can accumulate as much as we want at any stage. Each addition we make extends the range we can reach. So one way to think of the iteration might be:

```
while range r is too small:
  heap pop the highest fuel stop seen, f
  new_range = r + f
  heap push all stops between r and new_range
  r = new_range
```

Comment: How does that answer the question?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur I see room to interpret what the question is. Your idea of what the question actually is might be wrong.